# How to access multi visual replacement control in Spotfire 7 using Iron Python script?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am using a multi visual replacement control in Spotfire 7.0.
I would like to toggle the visualization (such as a cross table) which is part of this multi visual replacement control using iron Python script on a click of a button.
Does anyone know how to implement it?